# Gnome crashes when I drag to reorder favorites in Activities. Why?

Tags: gnome, crash, activities-overview

I recently installed `gnome-shell` to try it out (I've been using `openbox` alone, which I think I still prefer!) and my problem is that Gnome crashes (sometimes just restarts the DE, sometimes actually kills it all the way to login screen) when I drag to reorder **favorites** icons in the **Activities** sidebar.

Is this a known bug? I haven't found it (yet) on here.

*Ubuntu 16.04

Gnome 3.18

kernel 4.5*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no. The solution is not to change your icon theme.

The problem is that your cursor theme does not have some of the icons.

To fix `BMZ` cursor theme, for example, use this: https://gist.github.com/dylnmc/a6b880c1b0bbeb75f2a6218e3eef3121

You basically need to copy at least one of the files in `/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/cursors/` (I just picked this cursor theme because when I changed to it in gnome-tweak-tool, gnome did not crash) to your cursor theme in `/usr/share/icons/***/cursors/` where `***` represents the name of your cursor.

I don't know which icon it is, so I just copied everything that doesn't exist in `BMZ` from `/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/cursors/` to `/usr/share/icons/BMZ/cursors/`, as you can read in the gist above.

Answer (score 3):

You might be using the default X mouse cursor. Try changing it to something else. For example, `sudo apt-get install oxygen-cursor-theme` and set it in gnome-tweak tool.

Comment: I'll mark that as useful, because for one it helps, and two, you are the first person to show any love to my tumbleweed :D However, I want to know more why Gnome isn't working the way it's supposed to, as opposed to a workaround. I've since switched back to LXDFCE (lol) but I did like Gnome, sort of, and I am going to try it again on my Debian 8 machine using your suggestion. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had also this problem whit some cursor themes and changed to the default and it worked. But I wanted to use a more stylish cursor theme and I'm actually using one that works fine, no more crashes and really good design:

[Click here to see how it looks like ("La Capitaine" cursor theme)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrHCl.png)

Installation steps:

```
1) Copy git repository    
git clone https://github.com/keeferrourke/capitaine-cursors.git

2) Change to the copied directory from git
cd capitaine-cursors

3) Create directory to allocate the cursor theme
sudo mkdir /usr/share/icons/capitaine-cursors

4) Copy the content of bin/xcursor into the created directory
sudo cp -pr bin/xcursor /usr/share/icons/capitaine-cursors
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to start with an empty installation and add what I need; doing so left me with this bug. It looks like the default mouse cursor package which comes with a minimal Gnome desktop is `adwaita-icon-theme`. I am guessing that it doesn't include the 'grabbing hand icon' that is needed when re-arranging icons in the bar.

Simply `apt install adwaita-icon-theme-full` solved it for me.